# SQL query - variables based on excel cell

Tags: mysql, sql, excel

Good afternoon,

Below a sample of the SQL query I am using. I am trying to find a way for the statements in between ** to be variable and to be dictated by what value would be inserted in specific cells in the excel file.

Thanks in advance for your help !

Arnaud

```
And (V_ASSIGNMENTS.ASG_START_TIME>= to_date('**01NOV2021** 23:00:00','DDMONYYYY HH24:MI:SS'))
AND ((V_ASSIGNMENTS.ASG_START_TIME< to_date('**25NOV2021** 23:00:00','DDMONYYYY HH24:MI:SS')))
AND (LENGTH(V_CREWS.cre_alpha)=3)
--AND (V_CREWS.CRE_ALPHA like '2%')
AND V_ASSIGNMENTS.ASG_D_TYPE NOT LIKE 'RES'
-- AND V_CREWS.cre_alpha =('TBR')
--AND V_ASSIGNMENTS.ASG_D_TYPE IN ('FLT','POG') 
AND (V_CREWS.CRE_ALPHA='**KEJ**')
```

Comment: How are you going to get Excel to talk to this query, or are you building a query script in Excel to later run against the MySQL database

Comment: Hi RiggsFolly, this is a query that I have in an excel file from which I can adapt/refresh the query to get the data from the database.